# How does the new (probably in 4.17) linux kernel max macro work?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, macros, sizeof, preprocessor

This lwn article describes the new implementation of the `max` macro
in the linux kernel:

https://lwn.net/Articles/750306/#Comments

The macro has been changed to evaluate to a constant expression if
it is used with constant expressions. The problem was that `-Wvla`
triggers if an array length is not a constant expression.

The following is the code they use. (I factored out the two `_helper`
macros for better readability. I added `main` to show what the macros
do.)

```
#define __typecheck_helper(x, y) \
    ((typeof(x)*)1 == (typeof(y)*)1)

#define __typecheck(x, y) \
    (!!(sizeof(__typecheck_helper(x, y))))

#define __is_constant_helper(x) \
    (sizeof(*(1 ? ((void*)((long)(x) * 0l)) : (int*)1)))

#define __is_constant(x) \
    (sizeof(int) == __is_constant_helper(x))

#define __no_side_effects(x, y) \
    (__is_constant(x) && __is_constant(y))

#define __safe_cmp(x, y) \
    (__typecheck(x, y) && __no_side_effects(x, y))

#define __cmp(x, y, op) ((x) op (y) ? (x) : (y))

#define __cmp_once(x, y, op) ({ \
    typeof(x) __x = (x); \
    typeof(y) __y = (y); \
    __cmp(__x, __y, op); })

#define __careful_cmp(x, y, op) \
    __builtin_choose_expr(__safe_cmp(x, y), \
        __cmp(x, y, op), __cmp_once(x, y, op))

#define max(x, y) __careful_cmp(x, y, >)

#include <assert.h>

int main() {
    int var = 42;
    assert(sizeof(int) == __is_constant_helper(42));
    assert(1 == __is_constant_helper(var));
    assert(1 == sizeof(void));
    assert(1 == __is_constant(42));
    assert(0 == __is_constant(var));
    assert(42 == max(42, 0));
    assert(42 == max(var, 0));
    assert(1 == __is_constant(max(42, 0)));
    assert(0 == __is_constant(max(var, 0)));
    assert(&var == max(&var, var)); // warning
    assert(!"all checks passed"); // abort
}
```

My question:

`__is_constant_helper(x)` is the size of `int` for constant `x`
but 1 (the size of `void`) for  non-constant `x`. Why is that?

The rest of the implementation seems straight forward.
`__typecheck(x, y)` is only there to trigger an error if the types
are not compatible (https://lwn.net/Articles/749064/).

Answer (score 0):

Explained by Linus: https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/3/20/845

http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.5.15p6

> [Conditional operator] If both the second and third operands are
>   pointers or one is a null pointer constant and the other is a pointer,
>   the result type is a pointer to a type qualified with all the type
>   qualifiers of the types referenced by both operands. Furthermore, if
>   both operands are pointers to compatible types or to...